# Python: Small library for 3d-surface plots without dependencies to Matplotlib/Numpy

Tags: library, python, plotting

I need to deploy my python code as an .exe-file, which should generate quite a lot of 3d surface plots. Because of the deployment, I cannot use any library which relies on either Numpy, Pandas, Matplotlib etc, because this will cause **huge** filesizes of the .exe.

Unfortunately, plotly and bokeh only work well in the browser, i.e. generate interactive plots. To make a jpg/png from there, I'd need to also embed selenium browser into my exe for bokeh which is not really what I'm looking for.

That's why I'm wondering whether you know a "lean" (i.e.: small) library to generate surface plots? Apart from that, most of these heavy customization-possibilities are not needed at all, simply a good style and that's it.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you call huge exe sizes - at work I have a project that depends on MatPlotLib & Numpy as well as a lot of other things such as wxPython and when py2exe has been run the dist directory is 120 MB with 37 executable files and one zipped library (37 MB) and  which zips to a 51 MB file to distribute. While large by python standards that is very small by modern windows standards.